# Bind Alamofire request to table view using RxSwift

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rxalamofire

So I have been researching RxSwift for a couple days, and am trying to create a simple app with it. I have bound the searchController of my table to the results, which feed into the `cellForRowAt` function. How do I bind the alamofire response to each cell?
Which of these do I need to do?

- Use RxAlamofire to create an searchResultsArray
- Change searchResultsArray to a `Variable` and use `toObservable`?
- Bind `response` or `searchResultsArray` to create each cell.

The function I need to use is:

```
.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) {  row, element, cell in
    cell.textLabel?.text = "something"
}
```

This is my current RxSwift code:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var searchResultsArray = [[String:String]]()  
searchController.searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.filter { text in
        text.count >= 3
    }.subscribe(onNext: { text in
        searchRequest(search: text, searchType: "t:t") { response in
        self.searchResultsArray = response
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is my current cell creation function. `showSearchResults` changes when the cancel button is clicked.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {
            return UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        return cell
    }()
    if self.shouldShowSearchResults {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchResultsArray[indexPath.row]["result"]!
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchResultsArray[indexPath.row]["location"]!
    }

    return cell
}
```

This is my current api request:

```
func searchRequest(search: String, searchType: String, completionHandler: @escaping ([[String: String]]) -> ()) {
    let payload: [String: Any] = [
        "q": search,
        "fq": searchType,
        "start": 0
    ]

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.athletic.net/Search.aspx/runSearch")!
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: payload, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        let json = response.data
        do {
            var searchResults: [[String: String]] = []
            let parsedJson = JSON(json!)
            if let doc = try? Kanna.HTML(html: parsedJson["d"]["results"].stringValue, encoding: .utf8) {
                for row in doc.css("td:nth-child(2)") {
                    let link = row.at_css("a.result-title-tf")!
                    let location = row.at_css("a[target=_blank]")!
                    let schoolID = link["href"]!.components(separatedBy: "=")[1]
                    searchResults.append(["location": location.text!, "result": link.text!, "id":schoolID])
                }
            }
            completionHandler(searchResults)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the cellForRowAt with a RxSwift solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you presented, use of Rx will give you something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty
        .filter { text in text.count >= 3 }
        .flatMapLatest { text in searchRequest(search: text, searchType: "t:t") }
        .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) {  row, element, cell in
            if self.shouldShowSearchResults {
                cell.textLabel?.text = element["result"]!
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = element["location"]!
            }
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The `shouldShowSearchResults` feels out of place in that. But otherwise it looks good.

The above assumes you wrap your searchRequest in a function that returns an observable like this:

```
func searchRequest(search: String, searchType: String) -> Observable<[[String: String]]> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        searchRequest(search: search, searchType: searchType, completionHandler: { result in
            observer.onNext(result)
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

The above is a standard pattern that wraps a function that uses a callback into a function that returns an `Observable`.

Comment: That's awesome! Is it better for me to replace the closure with an Observable? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I expect that RxAlamofire has wrappers already written, but I don't normally use alamofire so I don't know for sure.

Comment: You might also enjoy looking over this example program. https://github.com/dtartaglia/RxEarthquake I'm happy to answer any questions you have about it, just post an issue with a question and I will answer it.

Comment: What if it returns an `Observable<[String: String]`> instead?

Comment: A table view needs an array of objects.